# Cleanly perform null checks in Angular HTML Template

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm wondering if there's a way to shorten the code here:

```
<td class="value">
    {{nonprofitRating?.financialRating?.performanceMetrics?.fundraisingEfficiency == null || ... == undefined ? ... : 'N/A' }}
</td>
```

to something more clean without adding getters to my .component.ts file. Is there a way to shorten the variable in Angular to something like in the below code block? This is information loaded into an NonprofitRating object from an API fetch call that may or may not be null or undefined, so I would prefer not to have 20 getters or 20 different variables in my .component.ts file for cleanliness purposes.

```
<td class="value" let fundraisingEfficiency = ...chained undefined check statement...>
    {{fundraisingEfficiency == null || ... == undefined ? fundraisingEfficiency.toFixed(2) : 'N/A' }}
</td>
```

Comment: IMO, performing these long checks in HTML makes the HTML unreadable. These checks should be abstracted out to a function and be placed in your component.ts file.

Comment: Really? Okay, I guess that's different than my own personal thought process, I wanted to keep the component.ts file clean as opposed to the HTML.

Comment: Read up on custom pipes, I use them for exactly this. Keeps the html nice and clean

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using ngSwitch to cleanly handle situations where the variable chaining would be too long, and avoid repetition. It also makes it very clean for handling if / else / then statements without mucking up the component.ts file, in my opinion.

```
<td class="value" [ngSwitch]="nonprofitRating?.accountabilityRating?.accountabilityTests?.materialDiversionOfAssets?.toLowerCase()">
    <mat-icon *ngSwitchCase="'pass'" style="color: green" style="color: green">check_circle_outline</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon *ngSwitchCase="'remediated'">remove_circle_outline</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon *ngSwitchCase="'fail'" style="color: red">cancel</mat-icon>
    <p *ngSwitchDefault>N/A</p>                        
</td>
```